# jqgrid columns not resizable after using setGridWidth

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code that displays a table in a window, it works fine when the user tries to resize the columns:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            datastr: $(some data string),
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            height: "auto",
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autowidth: true,                
            colModel: [ 
                { name:'lala', index: 'lala', , width:50, align:'center' },
                { name:'lele', index: 'lele', , width:50, align:'center' },
                .....
            ],
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false  },
            gridview:true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            autoencode: true,
            height: "100%",
            sortable: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                var $self = $(this);
                if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "jsonstring") {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(this).trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
                    }, 50);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

And all is good. However I wanted the table to resize when the window gets maximized and put back to normal, so I added the following:

```
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        $("#list").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(window).width()-30);
    }).trigger('resize');
```

Now the table re-size perfectly with the window BUT now the user can't re-size the column, can someone please let me know how to still get my table re-sizing with the window without losing my column feature of re-sizing?

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided in the following post:

[Jqgrid - window.bind event does not allow column resizing in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513518/jqgrid-window-bind-event-does-not-allow-column-resizing-in-ie8?rq=1)

For some reason comparing the sizes and updating accordingly did the trick, not sure why that's different than just updating it every time but it did work.